# Tomcat server remote redeployement

Tags: java, tomcat, jmx, shiro

We have a web app using Apache Shiro for security and deployed in a Tomcat 7 server, and an administration application in java swing. One of the purposes of the administration application is to manage urls access rights for users in the web application. When the rights are modified, the web app need to be redeployed. 
We are already using JMX to start/stop/reload the web app in Tomcat, but is there a way to redeploy the web app each time the shiro.ini file is updated?

Comment: If you can call "touch" to the war file, tomcat will re-deploy it. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Touch_%28Unix%29.

Answer (score 0):

The place where the `shiro.ini` file was apparently wrong (it was in the classpath root folder). We've just tried to move it to WEB-INF folder, and now, we don't need manual redeployement anymore. Just a reload of the web app eventually, and it is possible to do it with JMX.

Thank you dinesh707, you're comment helped us in some way.